GPU doesn't load if my monitor is turned off and pc is turned on by WOL
So i'm bit with a little problem:

PC for AI server, sometimes i need to turn on the pc by wol and the monitor is turned off. The pc turns on fine and the OS loads but after some hours, when i need to access the pc, i turn on the monitor and nothing, like the gpu never loaded, i even sometimes tried to turn off the monitor, turn the pc by wol and if i don't turn on the  monitor after passing the bios loading or GRUB, the graphics won't turn on until i restart the pc again.

Specs of the pc:

AMD Ryzen 5 5500
Motherboard MSI A320M Grenade
OS: Ubuntu Server 22.04
GPU: MSI Nvidia RTX 4060 Ti 16GB

Can someone help me? Is there something on the BIOS I can turn off/on to prevent this... or even something on GRUB or linux?
Expection: Turn on the pc by wol with monitor turned off and after some minutes when i need to use the pc physically (not remotely) i just turn on the monitor and done, no need to reboot the pc.
